# Multiple Magento 2 Sites Varnish Configuration

Tags: magento2, varnish, apache

I have a dedicated server centos 6 Apache I have different Magento 2 sites on the server with there own ip and domain. I have installed and configured Varnish for one site / ip running Magento 2 site and used the Varnish configuration file generated in the admin and uploaded to [Home]/etc/varnish and renamed the file as default.vcl below is the settings section.

My problem is if I try to add any more sites/ip the varnish will not restart shows failed. please can someone tell me exactly how to add more sites to the configuration file and I can fill in my ip accordingly.

Secondly I want to ask when I have different Magento 2 sites and 1 varnish when I clear cache in any site will it also clear / purge for all sites - or will they work independently

```
backend default {
    .host = "88.151.196.121";
    .port = "8080";
    .first_byte_timeout = 600s;
    .probe = {
        .url = "/pub/health_check.php";
        .timeout = 2s;
        .interval = 5s;
        .window = 10;
        .threshold = 5;
   }
}

acl purge {
    "localhost";
}

sub vcl_recv {
    if (req.method == "PURGE") {
        if (client.ip !~ purge) {
            return (synth(405, "Method not allowed"));
        }
```

Comment: Are these Magento sites hosted on the same machine and are they also served by `88.151.196.121`? If so, no changes are required, because Varnish will use the `Host` header and the URL to identify objects in cache. The same applies to clearing the cache.

Comment: Thanks - all sites are Magento 2 and hosted on same server - the servers main ip is 88.151.196.121 and one magento 2 site is running on this ip -    another Magento 2 site is running on ip address 88.151.196.123   - but as I mentioned varnish only seems to work on 1 site and I have to enter that ip in the configuration file - so confused

Answer (score 2):

Based on your comment, I can conclude that the 2 Magento sites are served on 2 different IP addresses.

These sites will be defined as 2 separate backends, because their IP address differs.

Let's take these backend definitions as an example:

```
backend backend1 {
    .host = "88.151.196.121";
    .port = "8080";
    .first_byte_timeout = 600s;
    .probe = {
        .url = "/pub/health_check.php";
        .timeout = 2s;
        .interval = 5s;
        .window = 10;
        .threshold = 5;
   }
}
backend backend2 {
    .host = "88.151.196.123";
    .port = "8080";
    .first_byte_timeout = 600s;
    .probe = {
        .url = "/pub/health_check.php";
        .timeout = 2s;
        .interval = 5s;
        .window = 10;
        .threshold = 5;
   }
}
```

Varnish has no way of knowing which backend to pick. If both sites were hosted on the same IP address, Varnish would use the value of the `Host` header to determine the various sites.

In this case, we'll need to create a *backend hint* to tell Varnish when to pick which backend. We could use hostname matching for this.

This means you'll have to add the following VCL code:

```
sub vcl_recv {
    if(req.http.host ~ "(www\.)?example.com") {
        set req.backend_hint = backend1;
    } else {
        set req.backend_hint = backend2;
    }
}
```

Because this is VCL, you can tailor these routing rules to your exact needs.

Comment: thank you for your kind reply please can you clarify this line I keep same or need to enter domain "(www\.)?example.com"

Comment: The `~` operator in VCL is there to match regular epxressions. In this case the regex is `"(www\.)?example.com"`, which matches `www.example.com` and `example.com`. You can put your own domain names in there. You can also use `==`  to match the string and use the `||` operator to match multiple domains instead of using regexes.

Comment: What would you do if both sites are on the same IP?

I've got the same problem with 2 sites in Plesk and I can't get the cache to flush in varnish without restarting it.

Comment: @wjp_bill the `Host` header will handle that issue. No need to define a separate backend. As long as each site's domain is reflected through the `Host` header, things will be fine.